# Circular reference between libc.so.6 and liblsp.so?

Tags: linux, glibc, libc

```
▶ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2b856000)
        /lib/$LIB/liblsp.so => /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so (0x00007f472effc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f472f3f5000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f472efd5000)

▶ldd /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe305ee000)
        /lib/$LIB/liblsp.so => /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so (0x00007f28eea81000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f28eea5a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f28ee868000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f28eee8d000)
```

We can find a circular reference between libc.so.6 and liblsp.so. How does it works?

Comment: Why should there be a problem?  It just means that anytime one of them is loaded, you also have to load the other.  The dynamic linker is smart enough not to infinitely recurse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it works?

1. `libc.so.6` doesn't *really* depend on `liblsp.so`. You can verify this with `readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep NEEDED`.
   The reason `ldd` shows it is that it's listed in your `/etc/ld.so.preload`.
2. As Nate Eldredge commented, this "cycle" doesn't matter -- the loader needs to load dependent libraries *which aren't already loaded*. If a library is already loaded, the loader simply increments its reference count.